# How to fetch the names of tables present in database

Tags: perl

I have a piece of code where I wanted to fetch the database information and store the required data, I am already connected to the database what I am looking for is to fetch the name of the tables present inside the database so that I can access them one by one and fetch the required information.

Here's my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
use strict;

use warnings;
use Switch;
use Data::Dumper;
use Spreadsheet::Read qw(ReadData);
my   @expValues ="";
my $portDes="";
my $portValue="";
my $ttidDes;
my $ttidValue;
my $tidvDes;
my $tidvValue;
my $tiDes;
my $tiValue;
my $redirectHostDes;
my $redirectHostValue;
my $saQueryDes;
my $saQueryValue;
my $dialedNumDes;
my $dialedNumValue;
my $dbType = "mysql"; 
my $database = "control";
my $host="localhost";
my $dsn="";
my $userid="";
my $password="";
if($dbType eq "mysql"){
$dsn = "DBI:$dbType:database=$database;host=$host:port=XXXX";
$userid = "XXXX";
$password = 'XXXX';
}else{
$dbType="postgres";
$userid = "postgres";
$password = "postgres";
$dsn = "DBI:$dbType:database=$database;host=$host,port=XXXX";
}

my $dbcon = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password) or die "Can't connect to database: $DBI::errstr\n";
print "connected to the database\n";


my $notables = $dbcon->tables();
print "No of tables : $notables" ;

sub getXlxsDetails(){
my $book = ReadData ($_[0]);
my $configrows = $_[1];
#print $configrows;
my @rows;
#my @port;
#my @ttid;
#my @ti;
#my @tidv;
#my @redirect;
#my @saQuery;
#my @dialed;
#my @returnInfo;
if($configrows eq ""){
    $portValue="Null";
    $ttidValue="Null";
    $tidvValue="Null";
    $tiValue="Null";
    $redirectHostValue="Null";
    $saQueryValue="Null";
    $dialedNumValue="Null";
    print ("NOT NULL**************************");
    return $portValue,$ttidValue,$tidvValue,$tiValue,$redirectHostValue,$saQueryValue,$dialedNumValue;
}
else{
if($configrows eq 'Development'){
@rows = Spreadsheet::Read::rows($book->[1]);
}
if($configrows eq 'Production'){
@rows = Spreadsheet::Read::rows($book->[2]);       
}
foreach my $i (1 .. scalar @rows) {
    foreach my $j (1 .. scalar @{$rows[$i-1]}) {
        my $key = $rows[$i-1][$j-1] // '';
        switch($key){
        case "Port Assigned " {
        print ("MATCHED************************** Port Assigned\n");
        $portDes = (($rows[$i-1][$j-1])."\n");
        $portValue = (($rows[$i-1][($j+1)-1])."\n");
        #@returnInfo[$j] = ($portValue);
        }
        case "TTID (Y/N, default: Y)" {
        print ("MATCHED************************** TTID (Y/N, default: Y)\n");
        $ttidDes= (($rows[$i-1][$j-1])."\n");
        $ttidValue=(($rows[$i-1][($j+1)-1])."\n");
        #@returnInfo[$j+1] = ($ttidValue);
       }
       case "TIDV (Y/N, default: Y)" {
        print ("MATCHED************************** TIDV (Y/N, default: Y)\n");
        $tidvDes=(($rows[$i-1][$j-1])."\n");
        $tidvValue= (($rows[$i-1][($j+1)-1])."\n");
        #@returnInfo[$j+2] = ($tidvValue);
        }
        case "TI (Y/N, default: Y)" {
        print ("MATCHED************************** TI (Y/N, default: Y)\n");
        $tiDes= (($rows[$i-1][$j-1])."\n");
        $tiValue=(($rows[$i-1][($j+1)-1])."\n");
        #@returnInfo[$j+3] = ($tiValue);
        }
        case "Redirect host FQDN (default)" {
        print ("MATCHED************************** Redirect host FQDN (default)\n");
        $redirectHostDes=(($rows[$i-1][$j-1])."\n");
        $redirectHostValue=(($rows[$i-1][($j+1)-1])."\n");
        #@returnInfo[$j+4] = ($redirectHostValue);
        }
        case "SA-Query URL" {
        print ("MATCHED************************** SA-Query URL\n");
        $saQueryDes=(($rows[$i-1][$j-1])."\n");
        $saQueryValue=(($rows[$i-1][($j+1)-1])."\n");
        #@returnInfo[$j+5] = ($saQueryValue);
        }
    case "Dialed Number (from SIP invite)" {
        print ("MATCHED************************** Dialed Number (from SIP invite)\n");
        $dialedNumDes= ($rows[$i-1][$j-1]);
        $dialedNumValue=($rows[($i + 1)-1][$j-1]);
        #@returnInfo[$j+6] = ($dialedNumValue);
        }

   }
        next;
}
}
return $portValue,$ttidValue,$tidvValue,$tiValue,$redirectHostValue,$saQueryValue,$dialedNumValue;
}


#@returnInfo = (\@port,\@ttid,\@ti,\@tidv,\@redirect,\@saQuery,\@dialed);


}
#my $Result=&getXlxsDetails(\@rowsDev,"Port Assigned ");
my ($result1,$result2,$result3,$result4,$result5,$result6,$result7)=&getXlxsDetails('024_Goldman_Sachs.xlsx','Development');
print($result1."\n".$result2."\n".$result3."\n".$result4."\n".$result5."\n".$result6."\n".$result7);
#print "@$result\n";

print "\n";
```

The output I am getting is:

```
(tc-lab-04) /home/trustid/switchadaptor/testauto/dataverificationtesting2/XL_Parsing>./aa.pl
**connected to the database**
No of tables : 1MATCHED************************** Port Assigned
MATCHED************************** SA-Query URL
MATCHED************************** TTID (Y/N, default: Y)
MATCHED************************** TIDV (Y/N, default: Y)
MATCHED************************** TI (Y/N, default: Y)
MATCHED************************** Redirect host FQDN (default)
MATCHED************************** Dialed Number (from SIP invite)
10272

Y

Y

N

ivr.localdomain

https://devapi-primary.trustidinc.com/tid

8332259639
```

--> It is giving me no. of table, instead of no. of tables I wanted to fetch the name of all the tables present in the database.

Code snippets I already used:

```
my @names = $dbcon->tables( $catalog, $schema, $table, $type );
print Dumper @names;
```

I am working on the Virtual Machine, basically it is my office lab server & the DB is deployed in this server.

Comment: *How to fetch the names of tables present in database* [The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-tables-table.html), [DATABASE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_database).

Comment: @akina it wont help me, i wanted to have a code snippet which work in perl.

Comment: @akina I am sry if I sounds wrong to you, what I meant was the link shared is taking me to my sql what I want is to understand how to execute this in perl . hope you got it.

Comment: Oh, I can help only with SQL part and not with Perl part. From the other side the quering INFORMATION_SCHEMA does not differ from the quering any other table/view.

Comment: @akina np, Thanks. I am looking for something like how to get the name of the tables present in unknown database using perl. have a good day!

Answer (score 4):

Using `$dbcon->tables()` as attempted in the question is a good way indeed, but that returns the list of tables -- while it is assigned to a scalar so you get the number of tables, as observed.<sup>†</sup>  Also, calling it without parameters is deprecated (see docs linked below). A correct way to use this is shown in the answer by Dave Sherohman.

Or, use [table_info](https://metacpan.org/dist/DBI/view/DBI.pm#table_info) (that [tables](https://metacpan.org/dist/DBI/view/DBI.pm#tables) is a "*simple interface to*"), to obtain and review more detailed information than just the names, and see which of the tables are suitable for your purpose

```
my $sth = $dbh->table_info('', '', '%', 'TABLE');
my $res = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;
print Dumper $res;
```

or with

```
my $sth = $dbh->table_info('', '', '', 'TABLE');
```

or even

```
my $sth = $dbh->table_info(undef, undef, undef, 'TABLE');
```

If you leave out that last `'TABLE'` (and use `''` or `undef` instead) then the `VIEW`s will be included in the resutls as well, what may be of interest.

---

<sup>†</sup>  The question also shows the correct

```
my @names = $dbcon->tables( $catalog, $schema, $table, $type );
```

but it doesn't tell us what happens with it and what all those variables are

Answer (score 2):

The previous comments and answer referring to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` should be noted as only applicable to MySQL/MariaDB.  Which, admittedly, is the database that your `DBI->connect` statement indicates you're using, but there is also a database-engine-independent way to do it:

```
my @tables = $dbcon->tables(undef, undef, undef, 'TABLE');
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to get the name of the tables present in unknown database

You may retrieve the names of the databases which are present on the server (including system databases) with

```sql
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS `Database`
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA;
```

You may retrieve the names of the tables in definite database with

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_schema = 'db_name';
```

or in current database with

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_schema = DATABASE();
```